# Can I create a custom onClickListener for multiple buttons

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have 12 buttons created onscreen, I don't need to create more programmatically.

What I do need is to have a generic onClickListener method that will determine which button was pressed and go into a case statement to determine what to do.

So normally I would have this:

```
b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //myFancyMethod(v);
        }
    });
```

Where button2 in xml is assigned to b2 in code and that onClick calls a FancyMethod.  Im thinking of something like:

```
switch(R.id()) {
        case R.id.button2:
            callMethodForButton2;
            return true;
```

but how can I do this?

Comment: Yes it IS a duplicate.  That question was what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

implement button.onclicklistener

```
public class ContactsDetailsActivity extends Activity implements Button.OnClickListener
```

in your oncreate

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);


Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then implement the methods by pressing alt enter then add your switch case statement

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1:
            "your code when btn1 is clicked"
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            "your code when btn2 is clicked"
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a generic onclick listener and assign it in `onCreate`:

```
private View.OnClickListener onClickListn = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           switch(R.id()) {
              case R.id.button2:
                 //callMethodForButton2;
                   return true;
              case R.id.button3:
                //Cintinue like this.
        }
    };
```

Create a button array and assign onClickListeners.

```
ArrayList<Button> btnArr = nea ArrayList<>;

btnArr.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.Button2));
//add every button lile this

for(Button btn:btnArr){
    btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListn);
}
```

Or you can do direct seting like

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.Button2)).setOnClickListener(onClickListn);
```